# Highlight cells based on multiple conditions - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I have a good solution to highlighting cells based on an exact condition. I'm trying to highlight based on multiple conditions.

This is the scenerio I'm trying to come up with:
If Column Dodge contains "Durango" and Column Color contains "Blue" then highlight Column Dodge word Durango only.

Updated a little bit:
The following highlights "Durango" if there is a match even though I identified "Blue" as well:

```
Sub highlight()

Dim highlight As Range
Dim highlight2 As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set w = ws.Rows(1).Find("Dodge", LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set s = ws.Rows(1).Find("Color", LookAt:=xlWhole)


If Not w Is Nothing Then
 For Each highlight In ws.Range(w, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, w.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
If Not s Is Nothing Then
 For Each highlight2 In ws.Range(s, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, s.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
    If highlight2 = "Blue" And highlight = "Durango" Then
       highlight.Interior.Color = 65535
       Else
    End If
Next
End If
```

Next
End If

End Sub

[image]

Comment: `If Highlight.offset(0, 2).value = "Blue" then`

Comment: Have you considered using conditional formatting?

Comment: The offset does work, but sometimes the column "color" will end up in a different area

Comment: Since the column "color" can be in any column, you should first do a `.Find` on the header row to identify which column is the color column then in your original code's loop, add in the additional condition as Warcupine said `Highlight.offset(0, #).value = "Blue"` where `#` is the color column which you found from `Find` (you will need to -1 from the column number to offset) @futureisnow

Comment: Got it! Thank you both for your help!